# Padding arrays with zeros dynamically - Octave / Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, padding

I have to add multiple arrays together in a for loop and the arrays will very in size so sometimes I will need to pad for the array x and sometimes I will need to pad for the array y how can I have the arrays padded dynamically?

**I know how to pad manually (see code below) but how can I do it dynamically if the size of the array x or the size of the array y will vary?**

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6]'
y = [3 5 7 8]';

A = x + [y;zeros(2,1)];

This will result in A = [4 7 10 12 5 6]'
```

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1 with is like matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the max length and pad both of them by the difference.

```
L = max(length(x), length(y));
A = [x; zeros(L-length(x),1)] + [y; zeros(L-length(y),1)];
```

It can easily be extended to more than two vectors:

```
L = max(length(x), length(y), length(z));
A = [x; zeros(L-length(x),1)] + [y; zeros(L-length(y),1)] + [z; zeros(L-length(z),1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do **not** have to pad the arrays in order to add them. You can do something like:

```
% Just some random arrays
A = rand(1, 10);
B = rand(1, round(rand(1,1)*10)+1);

% Then add them
if length(A) < length(B), C = A + B(1:length(A));
else C = B + A(1:length(B));

% Or...
C = A(1:max(length(A), length(B))) + B(1:max(length(A), length(B)));
```

What I suggest is just use the elements that matters. This means that you do not have to add zeros in the array but just add all the elements of the short *vector* with the same amount of elements from the larger *vector*.

The only reason to zero-pad the vectors is to make use of the `sum()` function of MATLAB for an *array* of NxM dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6]'
y = [3 5 7 8]';

L1 = length(x);
L2 = length(y);
if L1>L2
   A = x + [y;zeros(L1-L2,1)];
elseif L2>L1
   A = x + [y;zeros(L2-L1,1)];
else
    A = x + y;
end
```

This should check the lengths of both arrays and pad the smaller one to the size of the larger one.